# Angular Modules: Issue creating pure service module. Issues Resolving parameters

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-module, angular2-ngmodel

I am creating a Angular 4 module that has a service/provider in it.
The aim is for anyone project that imports the module to be able to inject the service.

Currently having issues resolving paramters for the service, in particular the `Http` from `@angular/http`.

Stack Trace:

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for CommonService: (?, [object Object], [object Object]).
      at ZoneAwareError (eval at webpackJsonp.../../../../script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports (addScript.js:20), <anonymous>:2571:38)
      at syntaxError (compiler.es5.js:1694)
      at CompileMetadataResolver.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.es5.js:15925)
      at CompileMetadataResolver.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (compiler.es5.js:15793)
      at CompileMetadataResolver.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getInjectableMetadata (compiler.es5.js:15779)
      at CompileMetadataResolver.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata (compiler.es5.js:16070)
      at compiler.es5.js:15999
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at CompileMetadataResolver.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata (compiler.es5.js:15959)
      at compiler.es5.js:15534
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at CompileMetadataResolver.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.es5.js:15525)
      at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.es5.js:26958)
      at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.es5.js:26931)
      at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.es5.js:26860)
```

If i add the `@Inject` decorator to the `http` parameter it no longer gives me the error on resolving the parameters for the `CommonService` but instead i get an issue resolving the `CommonService` in my `AppComponent`. My `AppModule` imports the `CommonServiceModule`

Stack Trace:

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent: (?).
    at ZoneAwareError (eval at webpackJsonp.../../../../script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports (addScript.js:20), <anonymous>:2571:38)
    at syntaxError (compiler.es5.js:1694)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.es5.js:15925)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (compiler.es5.js:15793)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata (compiler.es5.js:15388)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getEntryComponentMetadata (compiler.es5.js:16047)
    at compiler.es5.js:15629
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.es5.js:15629)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.es5.js:26958)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.es5.js:26931)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.es5.js:26860)
    at PlatformRef_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone (core.es5.js:4536)
    at PlatformRef_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule (core.es5.js:4522)
    at Object.../../../../../src/demo/main.ts (main.ts:11)
```

Any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Here is the Angular service module:

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule, Http } from '@angular/http';
import { CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import { CommonService } from './Common.service';
import { ServiceConfiguration } from '../service-config.model';
import { CommonServiceConstants } from './Common.constants';

export * from './Common.service';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HttpModule
    ]
})
export class CommonServiceModule {
    static withConfiguration(defaultHeaders: { [key: string]: string }, commonConfig: ServiceConfiguration): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: CommonServiceModule,
            providers: [
                CommonService,
                { provide: CommonServiceConstants.CommonConfigKey, useValue: commonConfig },
                { provide: CommonServiceConstants.DefaultHeaders, useValue: defaultHeaders }
            ]
        };
    }
}
```

here is the service:

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, RequestOptionsArgs } from '@angular/http';
import { Logger } from '../../logger';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BaseService } from '../base.service';
import { ServiceConfiguration, UrlConfiguration } from '../service-config.model';
import { Order, CommonResponse } from './Common.model';
import { CommonServiceConstants } from './Common.constants';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

export * from './Common.model';

/**
 * The Common Service
 * @export
 * @class CommonService
 * @extends {BaseService}
 */
@Injectable()
export class CommonService extends BaseService {

    /**
     * Creates an instance of CommonService.
     * @param {Http} http
     * @memberof CommonService
     */
    constructor(private http: Http,
        @Inject(CommonServiceConstants.CommonConfigKey) private CommonConfig: ServiceConfiguration,
        @Inject(CommonServiceConstants.DefaultHeaders) defaultHeaders: any) {
        super(defaultHeaders);
    }

    /**
     * Gets Common
     */
    public getCommon(retrievalType: string): Observable<CommonResponse> {
        const urlConfig = <UrlConfiguration>this.CommonConfig.urls[CommonServiceConstants.RetrieveCommonName];
        const startTime = performance.now();
        let retrievalUrl = urlConfig.url + CommonServiceConstants.RetrieveCommonEndpoint;
        retrievalUrl = retrievalUrl;

        return <Observable<CommonResponse>>this.http.get(retrievalUrl, <RequestOptionsArgs>{
            headers: this.getHeaders(urlConfig.headers, retrievalType),
            authType: this.CommonConfig.authType,
            params: {
                'commonRetrievalType': '' + retrievalType
            }
        })
            .map(
            (response) => {
                Logger.info(CommonService.name, 'Successfully retrieved Common. '
                    + ' type: ' + retrievalType, startTime);
                return response.json();
            }
            )
            .catch((error: any) => {
                Logger.error(CommonService.name, 'Error retrieving Common. '
                    + ' type: ' + retrievalType, error);
                throw (error);
            });
    }
}
```

My app component using the module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import {
  CommonServiceModule
} from '../../lib/index';

const config = { url: 'http://localhost:8090/application'};
const defaultHeaders = { 'applciation-id': 'AP1234' };

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonServiceModule.withConfiguration(defaultHeaders, <any>config),
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```